# Am I the only one annoyed by that "Have you considered accepting an answer or blah-blah-blah..."?

Tags: feature-request

Every time I see the "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" message it makes me feel guilty, which I don't think I am for simply asking an open-ended question. I want a button like "Yeah, shut up already!" or something...

Comment: It goes away in time. And if you have a good reason for not accepting any of the existing answer and don't feel a pressing need to get a better one, then don't worry about it.

Comment: What @dmckee says. It needs to be that prominent because some people simply don't realize that they can accept answers. Everyone else, just ignore it.

Comment: I'd like to see a link, as open-ended questions *are* frowned upon in SO.

Comment: Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

Answer (score 4):

While you’re right about some questions, you *could* accept answers on some other questions, e.g. on [Python: sort a part of a list, in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272819/python-sort-a-part-of-a-list-in-place).

Comment: I could if there were one. So far, there is no single answer on how do do that, and no definite "that's impossible" one, either.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like the ability to dismiss this message, like you can with the notification bar that appears on the top of the page.