# Is there any method to catch users who never accept answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, auto-acceptance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users)
> [Encourage users to select 'Accepted Answer' for old Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions)

Some users on Stack Overflow or Meta only ask questions, so many
users take their time to answer them but they do not bother to select
any best answer, and some don't even take time to upvote any of them.

So my question is whether there is any mechanism on the SO site to catch users
with no answer selection attitude and punish them in a way that active
users don't waste their time on these questions. Or I think SO should add a mechanism such that a highly voted answer will automatically be selected.

Comment: Do you actually mean cache? Or do you mean catch? Either way - no. It doesn't matter. Other users in the community will upvote good content. Accepted answers are just the asker's way of saying "thanks, this worked for me"

Comment: Also, once they've asked enough questions, their accept rate is displayed. If you don't want to answer questions for non-accepters, don't. But don't nag them about their accept rate.

Comment: Why this question is downvoted this much? i am not seen anything wrong in it.

Comment: [Downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: But i have seen that on meta there is monpoly of some users that they doesnot allow new user to post something thats why they downvote it

Comment: @Jason, your last comment is not true, I feel.

Comment: But i have seen that old users are posting anything and they are only getting upvotes and on meta new users are not allowed to ask something, take an example of my question, its not a local question at all, i have searched for it and doesnot found any answer so i posted it but -5 downvotes are too rude

Comment: Jason, the downvotes simply mean that people disagree with your (semi implicit) suggestion.

Comment: @DanielFischer but if so then you can flag my question and tell moderator to close it but this rapid downvotes will undo all my reputation which i got after so hard work

Comment: @Jason_vorhees - You have 1 question and 1 answer on meta... what hard work?

Comment: i am not talking for this time only, last time i have my account on meta and stackoverflow both, i have more then 100 repo on both but due to targetting by some users my repo is downvoted to one, so i deleted that account and recreated this

Comment: Its ok if someone find happiness in downvoting more then resolving problem of other's question then its their call, but i will try my level best on stackoverflow again and will not post any question on meta.

Comment: You've lost me. First, you're proposing to *punish* people who don't accept answers. Next, when folks disagree, you're suggesting to delete this question *and its two answers* to save you from downvotes? But then what about the work that Jim and Lix have put into their answers?

Comment: @Jas - you have to remember that posts and reputation here are a lot different than on the main site...  The main site might symbolize your technical capabilities while here on meta reputation is received for amongst other things, [very different things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)... Please don't be upset about it...

Comment: but before downvote their must be any creteria for this, not a random pick and drop manner

Comment: @kyle; why you removed my line, i have added it to make my answer delete soon to prevent further downvotes

Comment: I second what @Arjan said, but also Jason, you need to consider that on any non-meta site, downvotes are intended to be representative of the quality of the question according to that sites guidelines. In effect, a lot of downvotes are usually indicative of a "bad" question. Maybe the formatting was bad, maybe it was interpreted as a "plz send da codez" question, whatever, the point is the community considered it not a good fit for the site. Ask better questions, and you won't get downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @jason because deleting the question is not the correct action for this.  two others agreed with me, as I don't have edit privileges yet.

Comment: @arjan ahh, didn't know that. :P

Comment: Also, Jason, consider that deleting accounts and then recreating new ones to avoid the downvotes that come from bad questions will sooner or later most likely trip either an automated abuse detection script, or just annoy the devs/mods enough for them to take further action.

Comment: ok then its ok with me, now i have 10 downvotes only neede 17 more to make me 1 repo user and then nobody can harm me any more...hehhehhe

Comment: Just live with that, jeez. Down votes work like that on Meta, you can easily gain rep again.

Comment: Relevant example: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128174/167443) has a couple of valid, up-voted answers, but the asker has not accepted any of them. How do you suggest we punish this person?

Comment: @jin hello jin,here the answer are not what i suppose to get, this answers are to point out faults in my own question only, so i will definately select a answer if its directly related to my question and answering is not done to solve it.

Comment: @TheEstablishment good link to read, thanx 4 sharing it

Comment: @jin: answer to your question is that two answer of this question is even upvoted by me and i will chosse one from them if not got any other better answer

Comment: Thanx to the guy who upvoted this question and not followed the sheep pattern, this is what made me more confident, now i will again try on meta with new begining, thanx to the downvoters to to make me realise the power of unity(even if it is wrong or rite).

Comment: @Arjan one downvote not matter in compare to other 20 downvotes and other thing your 3rd point is not even cleared and yes i am aggainst the follow the ships rule so i cannot say my question is wrong because it is downvoted without even specifying the exect reason, and now downvotes are not bothering me, beacause i lost power of chat and other preivelages and soon voting power too, but i will never stop asking question which have not been correctly answered yet and thats my right.

Comment: I have not tagged you that time but the next reply is for you. I am not the person who ignores cumments and always reply them as sson as possible and yes i am bad in puntuations etc . But i never though that on social site puntuation matters this much, i will definately try to correct my puntuation in next post. Thanx for advise.

Comment: Really? You try to fight Community by removing the duplicate link?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd no my intention is not that i am just checking that can i edit closed question or not and my intention is not challenging community at all. I have also tried to re edit it but doesnot know how to do it.

Comment: Just don't edit. Nothing should be changed in the question. If you got anything else to ask start new question. If you have something to say to someone use `@` to notify him.

Comment: ok thanx for telling that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer rate is what you want to look at if you want to see a numerical representation of 
 a users
"no answer selection attitude".
[image]

[However it might not always be correct to take this measurement at face value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate)

You would have to consult each user on each question to confirm that they are actively and maliciously not voting or accepting an answer. :P

But on a serious note - you really have to read into each of these posts that the OP did not act upon.

Some sample conclusions from reviewing all of a users posts -

- The user simply hasn't been back to the site.

  - This can be frustrating at times.  Remember that there is a *real life world* out there beyond out little haven of knowledge that we have found here.  Once you have that coveted [fanatic badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/53/fanatic) and have already screwed your [visited/consecutive days rankings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile), you might go AWOL for a few days to clear you thoughts. You know...  Zen style...[image]
- Sometimes (depending on how long ago the post was) the OP might not feel that he has received enough attention on his/her post and wants to let the question trickle down from the [*fastest gun's in the west*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) to the [*hardcore bounty hunters*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127021/is-excessive-bounty-hunting-good-etiquette).
- Sometimes the OP *genuinely* finds that **none** of the answers that he was provided assist him in anyway - lets not rule out this possibility.

In addition, the system provides a reminder for users that have posted questions and not yet accepted any answers after a certain time period.  A [banner like structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjkxM.png) hovering in your profile view..

I believe that this might only be triggered if one of the answers has a positive score... Yet to be confirmed...

---

### TL;DR

**yes** - There is a mechanism in place. It doesn't *punish* the user per se, but [rather](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50452/feature-request-wake-up-and-accept-my-answer-please/50466#50466) [reminds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers/69777#69777) them to consider accepting one of the answers that were provided to his/her question[s].  Some users find [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/am-i-the-only-one-annoyed-by-that-have-you-considered-accepting-an-answer-or-bl) [rather](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-dont-forget-to-accept-reminder) [annoying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58561/dont-remind-me-to-consider-accept-answers-on-stackexchange) so that *might* be considered some type of punishment :)

> **/[M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?[S](https://stackoverflow.com/)[O|[F](https://serverfault.com/)|[U](https://superuser.com/)]/i** has it all... and then some...

Comment: TL&DR

yes - /M?S[O|F|U]/i has it all... and then some... what does it means

Comment: It means any of Stack Overflow/Server Fault/Super User and the meta sites for each.  What I mean is that the system *does* have a mechanism in place to remind users to consider accepting an answer.

Comment: thanx for the response, this is the far better answer i received yet.

Comment: At risk of over analyzing - What I meant is that the OP was inquiring about a mechanism to "detect and punish" users who refuse to accept answers.  Detection is handled by the display of the accept rate, and the "punishment" is in the form of an "annoying" banner. [so] already has these features (MSOFU has it all), plus many more features (and then some)...  In any case, thank you @Arj for your edits and citations!

Comment: Show off! (but +1 still :-))

Answer (score 14):

No. Accepting an answer is not mandatory. Other users in the community will upvote good/great content, and visitors will see the value in the answer regardless of the presence of a little green check.

Accepting an answer is just a way for the asker to say "Hey, this worked for me to fix my problem".

[FAQ about accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/167443)

Answer (score 9):

You should *never* require anybody to accept an answer - this has been discussed time and time again on MSO that it just isn't an entertaining discussion anymore. See, for example [New users who don't realise how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125584/new-users-who-dont-realise-how-to-accept-an-answer), the list just goes on and on.

Long story short - requiring users to accept an answer will make them accept **any** answer and that is exactly the opposite of what we are trying to achieve.

> Or I think SO should add a mechanism such that a highly voted answer will automatically selected.

You do realise, I hope, that since you are so concerned with your rep, that any answer you provide that receives two or more upvotes has already gained you more reputation than an accepted answer? Besides which, the highest voted answer naturally floats to the top anyway.

The point of the SE network is to provide good answers to good questions - that's all. The fact that a little game theory has been applied and you get rep and badges is a means to an end - it is not the end itself.